# Multivalued Dependencies

Tags: functional-dependencies

For a Relational Schema
Teaching(Course,Books,Lecturer)

Hows Course →→ Books and Course →→ Lecturer multivalued dependencies?

For a particuar Course we cannot be sure about the book name! As many books are possible! So hows it a FD in first case?

Comment: What's your question again? And what's an FD?

Comment: FD=Functional Dependency

Comment: Myth17, add your answer to the question, and add details to make it clearer.

Comment: A Functional Depency is on Primary Key right?? So for a particular Social Security Number we can be particular about the names and other details...
But for a Course name, we cannot come up with a particular book! Hows it a FD then?? And precisely a Multivalued Dependencies??

Comment: Who is saying that there is a FD? Are you referring to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_dependency? That seems to agree with you.

Comment: @djna Yup!Reffering to the wiki entry!

Comment: This is incomprehensible. No sentence in your post or comments is clear, and it's not clear what you are trying to say or ask about FDs or MVDs. Including: It's not clear what you were given or what the business rules/constraints are or what you think a double arrow means or what FDs or MVDs you think there are or or aren't or why. Please: Clarify via edits, not comments. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Ask 1 specific (researched non-duplicate) question. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 1):

These are not functional dependencies but multivalued dependencies (they are usually denoted with a double-headed arrow). Course -->---> Books means that once the course has been fixed all lecturers should use all books, i.e., whenever (L1,B1) and (L2,B2) correspond to a certain course, so should (L2,B1) and (L1,B2).

Course -->---> Books trivially implies Course -->---> Lecturer since both of them refer to the same pair of books and lecturers. In general, whenever X -->--> Y it also holds that X -->--> R-Y where R is the set of all attributes.